# How to only show preview in OptionMenu Tkinter python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, optionmenu

say i create and OptionMenu:

```
menu1 = OptionMenu(root, var, *list1, command = func ).pack()
```

with a function func() that returns the selection:

```
def func(value):
   return value
```

if the list list1 is formatted:

```
list1 =  [["one", "two", "three"], ["four", "five", "six"]]
```

how am i able to only show the first index of each sub list in the drop OptionMenu while still returning the whole sub list upon selection through the func() method?

Comment: Returning a value from `func` is pointless, because the code that calls the function (the event loop) ignores the return value.

Comment: @BryanOakley what do you suggest then?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the chosen value, just use `var.get()`. And if you don't want to display the list, but just the first value, you can use a dictionnary to associate each menu choice with the right list:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

dic = {"one": ["one", "two", "three"], "four": ["four", "five", "six"]}

var=tk.StringVar(root)

def func(arg):
    print(dic[arg])

menu1 = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *dic.keys(), command=func).pack()

root.mainloop()
```